# How to configure data representation in richselect?

Tags: javascript, html, webix

I have a question regarding richselect's data in Webix. I follow this sample
http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.suggest_textvalue_config.html

```
{
  view:"richselect",
  options:{
    textValue:"name",
    data:[
      { name:"Pen" },
      { name:"Apple" },
      { name:"Pineapple" }
    ]      
  }
}
```

Using `textValue`, I am able to define the attribute that will appear in the input, but not in the list of options. But how can I do that?

TIA

Comment: This is because you are not setting the value of the control via the "value" property. "name" property used by you just works as name of an input.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please show an example? I'm afraid I do not understand, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disagree. 
Richselect's suggest includes a list, therefore there's a possibility to modify its template. Here:

```
webix.ui({
  view:"richselect",
  options:{                 // suggest
    textValue:"name",
    body:{                  // list
      template:"#name#",
      data:[
        { name:"Pen" },
        { name:"Apple" },
        { name:"Pineapple" }
      ]      
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Loj for this another way.

Answer (score 0):

For the richselect list to show the values in the list you must use the **value** property as shown in the below example.

```
webix.ui({
   view:"richselect",
   options:{
   textValue:"name",
   data:[
      { value:"P", name:"Pen" },
      { value:"A", name:"Apple" },
      { value:"PA", name:"Pineapple" }
    ]      
   }
});
```

Hence, in you richselect list it will show *P, A & PA*; but when you click on *P* it will show the corressponding name *Pen* in the input because you have used ***textValue:"name"*** in your code.

Comment: I see. So the name cannot be visible in the popup instead of value?

Comment: Yeah, you must define the values.